# Custom Kalman Filter not producing desired Maximum Likelihood Estimates in R

Tags: r, filter, kalman-filter

I am attempting to implement the local level model in R - for a reference see http://personal.vu.nl/s.j.koopman/documents/LLIntro2011.pdf. I have implemented the code below. For any input data `mydata` the maximum likelihood estimates are giving the same number for sigma_n and sigma_e. I do not know what the source of the problem is.

```
locallevel <- function(x,data) {
sigma_e <- exp(x[1])
sigma_n <- exp(x[2])
len <- length(data)
y <- matrix(data,nrow=len,ncol=1)
a <- matrix(0,nrow=len,ncol=1)
v <- matrix(0,nrow=len,ncol=1)
F <- matrix(0,nrow=len,ncol=1)
P <- matrix(0,nrow=len,ncol=1)
K <- matrix(0,nrow=len,ncol=1)

for (i in 1:len) {

    if(i==1) {
    a[i]=y[i] 
    P[i]=sigma_e+sigma_n 
    F[i]=P[i]+sigma_e
    v[i]=y[i]-a[i]
    } else {
    a[i]=a[i-1]+((P[i-1])/(P[i-1]+sigma_e))*(y[i-1]-a[i-1])
    P[i]=((P[i-1]*sigma_e)/(P[i-1]+sigma_e))+sigma_n
    F[i]=P[i]+sigma_e
    v[i]=y[i]-a[i]
    }

}   


loglik =  -(len/2)*log(2*pi)-0.5*sum(log(abs(F))+((v^2)/F))
loglik  = -loglik

}

mlest<-optim(c(log(var(mydata)),log(var(mydata))),function(x) {locallevel(mydata,x)})
```

Comment: Could be many things. Try breaking the code down into smaller parts, checking if each of the steps works out as you would expect. In the last line, you call `locallevel(mydata,x)` whereas your function expects `x` before `data`.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the solution!